# How do I change the config items in a repo in BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I have a BitBucket repo as a target of a mirror but it is rejecting the push with an error message about it does not accept push requests.

Apparently I need to change the config value:

receive.advertisePushOptions

but this is not shown in the GUI.

Is there a way to access the git options which are not shown in the GUI without physically logging into the machine and changing them on the command line?